# v2.login is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I'm trying to validate the following form:

```
// JS
$scope.fields = [
  { text: 'Username', type: 'text', value: ''},
  { text: 'Phone', type: 'text', value: ''},
  { text: 'Password', type: 'password', value: ''},
  { text: 'Confirm password', type: 'password', value: ''}
]

$scope.login = function () {
  console.log('Logged in')
}

// HTML
<div class="user">
  <h2 class="header">Log in</h2>
  <form name="login">
    <div ng-repeat="field in fields">
      <input class="form-control" type="{{ field.type }}" placeholder="{{ field.text }}" ng-model="field.value" name="{{ field.text }}" required />
      <div ng-show="(login[field.text].$touched || login.$submitted) && (login[field.text].$error.required)">
        <span class="help-block">Please enter {{field.text}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="btn primary" href="javascript:;" ng-click="login()">Log in</a>
    <a href="#/signup">Sign up</a>
    <a href="#/forgot-password">Forgot password</a>
    <a id="skip" href="#">Skip</a>
  </form>
</div>
```

When I submit the form I get `v2.login is not a function`.

What could be the cause?

I don't have any variable called `v2`.

**EDIT:**

I changed the code to this:

```
// JS
$scope.submit = function () {
  console.log('Logged in')
}

// HTML
<div class="user">
  <h2 class="header">Log in</h2>
  <form name="login" ng-submit="submit()">
    <div ng-repeat="field in fields">
      <input class="form-control" type="{{ field.type }}" placeholder="{{ field.text }}" ng-model="field.value" name="{{ field.text }}" required />
      <div ng-show="(login[field.text].$touched || login.$submitted) && (login[field.text].$error.required)">
        <span class="help-block">Please enter {{field.text}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input class="btn primary" type="submit" value="Log in" />
    <a href="#/signup">Sign up</a>
    <a href="#/forgot-password">Forgot password</a>
    <a id="skip" href="#">Skip</a>
  </form>
</div>
```

Now nothing happens. There's no even a `Logged in` message popping up when I click submit.

Comment: Can you show us how your controller is defined in HTML and called? Do you use a router? It seems like a problem that could be caused by incorrect usage of `controllerAs` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define ng-controller on html Page.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the form name to something else. Both ng-click function and name should not be the same.

Comment: I changed the name (turned it into a `ngSubmit`). Now nothing happens. Please see my **EDIT**.